# Button not moving randomly

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, arc4random

I want a button to appear randomly and have a user click on it. However if they don't press it in the right amount of time it disappears and I want it to move to a different location. However, whenever I don't click on it, it appears right back in the same position on the screen. Here is my code.

```
    -(IBAction)randomRed:(id)sender
{

    [self redDot];

    CGRect senderFrame = [sender frame];
    CGRect superBounds = [[sender superview ] bounds];
    senderFrame.origin.x = (superBounds.size.width - senderFrame.size.width) * drand48();
    senderFrame.origin.y = (superBounds.size.height - senderFrame.size.height) * drand48();
    [sender setFrame:senderFrame];

    counter = counter-1;

    [self performSelector:@selector(showRedDot) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];   
}

-(void)startRedDot
{

    if (counter ==0)
        redDot = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(showRedDot)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];

}

-(void)showRedDot
{
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        [redButton setAlpha:1];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        [self performSelector:@selector(redDot) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    }
}
-(void)redDot
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [redButton setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

drand48() is a seeded random generator, so it is only psuedo-random. At the beginning of your program, you can call srand48(int), and then when you need a random number, use drand48(). The integer you use in srand48(int) is the "seed" for your random numbers; that is to say, the sequence of "random" numbers will be the same every time you use that seed.

Not so random, you say? If you want something more so, try arc4random(). To make life easier, you can use (arc4random() % x) to get random numbers on the range 0 - (x-1).

Hope this helps!